# IIS 10.0 - using mod_rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I develop websites on my local machine (windows 10 with IIS 10.0) and then upload them to a linux server where it uses the .htaccess files (mod_rewrite format) for url rewriting.

Is there any way possible to use this mod_rewrite format on my local machine (iis 10)? Every attempt I have made so far has failed to work.

[This post](http://www.nelsonpires.com/web-development/ionics-isapi-rewrite-filter-aka-iirf-for-iis8/) mentions that an update version of ionic's isapi rewrite is available, but even this updated file does not appear to work for IIS10.

Also: I am aware that you can import rewrite rules through IIS Manager -> Url Rewrite -> (Actions) Import Rules. This however has not been ideal for my situation.

Would the best course of action for me, to be to run [something like this apache server](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx) on my windows 10 machine and have websites setup through there for testing (which may then support the .htaccess files)?

Any advice, solutions, knowledge, feedback is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you're using Apache on your live machine you should develop with that. You're going to cause a headache for yourself. You can use prebuilt setups like xampp or wamp on windows.

Comment: Even better, run a small VM with VirtualBox, and put Ubuntu server on it. Install ‘Guest Additions’ So you can have a shared folder. You can still develop in Windows but your server will be practically as good as a real one. Just make sure Apache can [access the shared files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52667).